# Dailymotion activities API specification

Tags: dailymotion-api

There is no specification available for the possible values of the fields "type", "object_type" and "from_type" in the documentation of the Activity API.

I was hoping to retrieve activities for some events like:

- Removing a video from a playlist
- Adding a video to a playlist after having removed it from the same playlist (no activity in that case)
- Adding a playlist
- Editing a video (rename/change description or any other edit)

My question is :

Is there any way to retrieve those events with the Activity API? Is there any full specification for the "type" fields?

API types I know are for example :

- user.addVideoToPlaylist
- user.postVideo
- user.startLiveStream
- user.addComment

The documentation URL: http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/obj-activity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right by saying that the documentation is lacking on this front. We're going to remedy this situation in the near future. In the meantime, here is the current list of activity types available for you to use.

**For users:**

- `user.postVideo`
- `user.addVideoToPlaylist`
- `user.rateVideo`
- `user.bookmarkVideo`
- `user.addComment`
- `user.joinGroup`
- `user.addVideoToGroup`
- `user.subscribeUser`
- `user.likeVideo`
- `user.startLiveStream`
- `user.subscribeChannel`

**For groups:**

- `group.memberJoin`
- `group.videoAdd`
- `group.noteAdd`

**For playlists:**

- `playlist.videoAdd`

**For channels/categories:**

- `channel.featuredVideo`